# C++ pass member function of class template as argument

Tags: c++, templates

I've got a **class template** in which I want to **pass a function as an argument to another member function**

MyClass.h:

```cpp
template<typename CT>
class MyClass {
public:
  double linfun(double x) { return 0.5 * x + 3.; }
  virtual double some_method();
  virtual double solver(std::function<double(double)> f, double k);
}
```

MyClass.cpp:

```cpp
template<typename CT>
double MyClass<CT>::some_method() {
  // do some calculations ...
  x = 42.;
  // Call solver function with linfun as argument:
  return solver(linfun, x);
}

template<typename CT>
double MyClass<CT>::solver(std::function<double(double)> f, double k) { 
  return f(k); 
}
```

#### Problem/Error

This gives me the error:

```
nonstandard form for taking the address of a member function  
    return solver(linfun, x);  
                  ^
no suitable constructor exists to convert from "double (double)" to "std::function<double (double)>"
    return solver(linfun, x);
                  ^
          detected during instantiation of "void MyClass<CT>::some_method() [with CT=SomeClassType]" at line 1234 of "SomethingElse.C"
```

#### What I tried:

I tried all proposed solutions I found, f.i.:

```cpp
return solver(this->*linfun, x);
```

**-> Same error**

Next with this:

```cpp
return solver(this->linfun, x);
```

With the following error:

```
error: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function
    return solver(this->linfun, x);
                        ^
```

Any idea how to make this possible? I'm not restricted to using `std::function`, but I'd prefer so.

Comment: -> `static double linfun(double x)`.

Comment: or `solver([this](double x) { return linfun(x);}, x);`.

Comment: *"in the MyClass.C file: [template code]"* See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Thanks, unluckily I do not really understand where and how to implement this. I edited my question slightly and moved the solver definition to the MyClass.C file. How and where could I implement your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a non-static member function without an object, so you can't just convert it to a `std::function`.

There are several other suggestions you could use.

1. Make the function `static` or a free function (the "minimal change" option - the function uses no class members).
2. Use a lambda object (the "modern" option when you need a non-static member).

```
return solver([this](double y) { return linfun(y); } , x);
```

3. Use an actual "pointer-to-member-function" parameter (the "quickly becomes unreadable and only works with non-static member functions of this particular class" option):

```
template<typename CT>
class MyClass {
public:
  double linfun(double x) { return 0.5 * x + 3.; }
  virtual double some_method();
  double solver(double (MyClass::*)(double) f, double k) { return this->*f(k); };

// ...
template<typename CT>
double MyClass<CT>::some_method() {
  // do some calculations ...
  x = 42.;
  // Call solver function with linfun as argument:
  return solver(&linfun, x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great for my minimum example. I'll give it a try with a real world example. Unluckily this will include functions which **require access to class members** *and* functions with **several arguments**, which makes the lambda option quite... bulky... But I guess lambda still will be the best option!

Comment: First quick test with my real class, also using class members: lambda works like a charm! I'll give it a more in-depth try tomorrow. Is there any way to simplify the lambda for the daily use, f.i. by defining a macro?